# Computing derivatives of a moment generating function

Tags: numerics, calculus-and-analysis

Dear Mathematica users,

I'm trying to compute higher order derivatives of a moment generating function and then evalutate them in 0 (in order to get some moment conditions for a GMM estimation).
Although I try to declare constants at the beginning of my script, which follows:

```
% Declaring constants    
Constants -> {kappa, theta, sigma, gamma, b, dt, Uy, J, phi, lambda}

%
A[Uv_] = (-(kappa *theta)/(sigma^2))*((gamma + b)*dt + 
  2*Log[1 - ((gamma + b + (sigma^(2))*Uv)/(2*gamma))*(1 - 
        exp[-gamma*dt])]) + (exp[Uy*J] - 1 - Uy*phi*J)*lambda*dt;

%
B[Uv_] = -(a*(1 - exp[-gamma*dt]) - 
  Uv*(2*gamma - (gamma - b)*(1 - exp[-gamma*dt])))/(2*
  gamma - (gamma + b)*(1 - exp[-gamma*dt]) - 
 Uv*(sigma^(2))*(1 - exp[-gamma*dt]));

% My moment generating function
EVPsi[Uv_] = exp[A[Uv]]*(1 - B[Uv]/omega)^(-v)
```

My problem is due to the fact that when I compute the first order derivative by using

```
EVPsi'[Uv] /. Uv -> 0
```

I get the following expression

```
% First derivative of the mgf evalueated in Uv=0
-v (1 + (a (1 - exp[-dt gamma]))/(
omega (2 gamma - (b + gamma) (1 - exp[-dt gamma]))))^(-1 - 
 v) (-((2 gamma - (-b + gamma) (1 - exp[-dt gamma]))/(
 omega (2 gamma - (b + gamma) (1 - exp[-dt gamma])))) + (
a sigma^2 (1 - exp[-dt gamma])^2)/(
omega (2 gamma - (b + gamma) (1 - exp[-dt gamma]))^2)) exp[
dt lambda (-1 - J phi Uy + exp[J Uy]) - (
kappa theta (dt (b + gamma) + 
   2 Log[1 - ((b + gamma) (1 - exp[-dt gamma]))/(2 gamma)]))/
sigma^2] + (
kappa theta (1 + (a (1 - exp[-dt gamma]))/(
omega (2 gamma - (b + gamma) (1 - exp[-dt gamma]))))^-v (1 - 
exp[-dt gamma]) Derivative[1][exp][
dt lambda (-1 - J phi Uy + exp[J Uy]) - (
kappa theta (dt (b + gamma) + 
   2 Log[1 - ((b + gamma) (1 - exp[-dt gamma]))/(2 gamma)]))/
sigma^2])/(
gamma (1 - ((b + gamma) (1 - exp[-dt gamma]))/(2 gamma)))
```

What I'm missing here is why I get in the last lines an expression such as

```
Derivative[1][exp][product of constants!!]
```

instead of a 0.

I would be thankful if you could shed some light on this.
Thank you.

Comment: `Exp` has capital E (like all _Mathematica_ functions).

Comment: Thank you very much b.gatessucks!

Comment: `%` does not delimit a comment.

Answer (score 3):

With *cleaned-up* version of of your code

```
 (* Declaring constants: Constants->{κ,θ,σ,γ,b,dt,Uy,J,ϕ,λ} *)
 (* how about a and v ?*) 
 aa[uv_] := (-(κ*θ)/(σ^2))*((γ + b)*dt + 
  2*Log[1 - ((γ + b + (σ^(2))*uv)/(2*γ))*(1 -
         Exp[-γ*dt])]) + (Exp[y*j] - 1 - y*ϕ*j)*λ*dt;
 bb[uv_] := -(a*(1 - Exp[-γ*dt]) - 
  uv*(2*γ - (γ - b)*(1 - 
        Exp[-γ*dt])))/(2*γ - (γ + b)*(1 - 
    Exp[-γ*dt]) -  uv*(σ^(2))*(1 - Exp[-γ*dt]));
 (* My moment generating function *)
 EVPsi[uv_] := Exp[aa[uv]]*(1 - bb[uv]/ω)^(-v)
```

using

```
EVPsi'[uv] /. uv -> 0
```

gives

[image]

**Related material from the Documentation Center:**

[MomentGeneratingFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MomentGeneratingFunction.html)

[image]

[Moment](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Moment.html)

[image]

Comment: Kguler, thank you for your reply! I managed to fix it. Actually, v and Uv are different. v is a constant, while Uv is my variable. Can Mathematica confuse between them? Should I change the v?

Comment: @JamesS., my pleasure. Welcome to Mathematica.SE.

Comment: @JamesS., updated removing the part that replaces `v` with `uv`. It is a good idea to get in the habit of using  variables and functions that start with lowercase letters to avoid possible conflicts with built-in Mathematica functions.

Comment: (+1) `k! SeriesCoefficient[EVPsi[t], {t, 0, k}]` will compute the `k`th moment.  (With this particular function `EVPsi`, and keeping the constants as unevaluated symbols, be prepared to wait a while when `k` exceeds $4$,though.  The case $k=4$ took 76 seconds and timing approximately doubles for each increment in $k$.)

Comment: @kguler whuber Thank you very much guys for your precious suggestions!